# Huge exception handling blocks in Java

Tags: java, exception

At the moment i working with library which can throw hell alot of different exceptions(8-10 per method call) and most of them must be handled, worse of all every method (at any time) can throw `AuthenticationExpiredException`, and i must re-attempt to authenticate. For example:

```
try {
        xStream = xSet.createXStream(id, binding, mimeType); //Method call
    } catch (AuthenticationExpiredException authenticationExpiredException) {
        try {
        this.authenticate(); // re-authenticate
        xStream = xSet.createXStream(id, binding, mimeType); //Method call again
        } catch (XAMException xamException) {
        throw new ConnectorException(
            "Error occurred during creating new Blob after attempting to re-authenticate",
            xamException);
        }
    } catch (XSystemCorruptException xSystemCorruptException) {
        this.entities.clear();
        this.closeConnection();     

        throw new ConnectorException("XSystem was corrupt and connection was closed",
            xSystemCorruptException);
    } catch (XSetCorruptException xSetCorruptException) {
        this.closeEntity(entity);

        throw new ConnectorException("XSet for entity: " + entity.getXuid()
            + " was currupt and removed", xSetCorruptException);
    } catch (XAMException xamException) {
        throw new ConnectorException(
            "Error occurred during creating new Blob.", xamException);
    }
```

And this is one of the smallest examples of exception handling. The main question here, is there any way to reduce amount of code which handle exceptions, and make logic cleaner?

#### UPDATE

Thanks for your feedback. I decided to create separate wrapper for this library by wrapping every method and handling them respectively. To support different handling methods i created interface for wrapper and then implemented it with my custom wrapper like this:

```
public interface XAMLibraryWrapper{
    // Methods
}

/**
 * Will attempt to recover before throwing RuntimeException
 */
public class RecoveringXAMLibraryWrapper implements XAMLibraryWrapper{
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: I'm not claiming that this is the **best** idea, but you could write a thin wrap around the library with your own code and wrap any exception into a runtime exception (so you don't need to catch 8-10 exceptions per method call) and the API wrapper could handle the retry too. What I'm trying to say is that I would separate this library from the business logic, and present an Adapter/Bridge in the simplest way as possible to the business logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If** there is a consistent way to handle those method (i.e. you always wrap them in the same way and re-throw a `RuntimeException`, then a custom wrapper library *might* be the appropriate approach. This can still work when there are 2-3 different ways to handle them (by providing 2-3 wrapper methods (or even classes) for a single wrapped method/class).

Alternatively, if two or more exception types have the exact same handling code, then you can try to look for Java 7 [to get multi-catch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern. [JdbcTemplate](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java/) is a wonderful example how this design pattern can simplify exception-heavy code (`SQLException`s in this case).

Answer (score 2):

If the API is indeed designed to throw that many exceptions, and each of them requires different handling, then there isn't much you can do.

One thing you can do is  move repeated code in a separate method, or use Java 7 multi-catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different things to do for each exception I'm afraid all those catch statements might be necessary. However, if you have lot's of catch statements with the same content or lot's of resources to close, you might have a look into the new Java 7 features like multiple exceptions in one catch and automatic resource handling. I'm not sure Java 7 is an option for you though.